# Download poppler automatically by using setup file

Tags: python, pdf, package, poppler

I'm making python file using pdf2image to convert pdf to image. But it needs poppler on user's machine.
But the problem is when I want to use my python file on the other computer, I need to install it every time. Can I download it automatically by using setup.py? or I need to put poppler file in my project directory and download it as a folder.

Answer (score 0):

After Doing Some Research I Found This On  [Python's Official Documentation](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

Even I didn't Knew How To Solve This So Credits To Python's Awesome Docs

#### Here is your answer-

```
import setuptools
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
name="example-pkg-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE", # Replace with your own username
version="0.0.1",
author="Example Author",
author_email="author@example.com",
description="A small example package",
long_description=long_description,
long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
url="https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject",
packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
classifiers=[
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
],
python_requires='>=3.6',
```

)

### Hope This Will Help

#### Happy Coding!